# useRecoilCallback not updating state on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

Why is this code not working?

The `updateCurrentSong` is not even running on click

```
    const currentSong = useRecoilValue(currentSongState)

    const updateCurrentSong = useRecoilCallback(({snap, set}) => () => {
        set(currentSongState, prev => ({...prev, playing: !currentSong.playing}))
    }, [currentSong])

    return (
        <div onClick={updateCurrentSong()} >
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I think it's because you have parentheses in your onClick attribute. I believe it should be like this:

```html
<div onClick={updateCurrentSong}>
...
</div>
```